# Save result from flip-flop in variable?

Tags: regex, perl

I have about 1kB of text from STDIN

```
my $f = join("", <STDIN>);
```

and I would like to get the content between `open1` and `close1`, so `/open1/../close1/` comes to mind.

I have only seen it been used in one liners and in scripts in while-loops and `$_`.

**Question**

How can I get the result from `/open1/../close1/` in my script when everything is in `$f`?

Comment: So you want the lines starting from `/open1/` up to `/close1/` stored in `$f`?

Comment: Ideally the result should go in another variable, so `$f` isn't overridden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Capturing all matches with a single regular expression

If you want to capture all the lines between `open1` and `start1` markers *(excluding the markers)*, it is easily done with a single regular expression:

```
my $f = join("", <STDIN>);

my @matches = ( $f =~ m/\bopen1\b(.*?)\bclose1\b/gs );

for my $m (@matches) {
  print "$m";
}
```

where

- `s` modifier treats the string as a single line;
- `g` modifier captures all the matches;
- `(.*?)` matches a group of any characters using the [lazy quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy)

## Using the range operator

The range operator (so-called flip-flop) is not very convenient for this task if you want to avoid capturing the markers, because an expression like `/open1/ .. /close1/` returns *true* for the lines matching the patterns.

The expression `/^open1$/ .. /^close1$/` returns *false* until `/^open1$/` is *true*. The left regular expression stops being evaluated once it matches the line, and keeps returning *true* until `/^close1$/` becomes *true*. When the right expression matches, the cycle is restarted. Thus, the `open1` and `close1` markers are included into `$matches`.

It is even less convenient, if the input is stored in a variable, because you will need to read the contents of the variable line by line, e.g.:

```
my $matches = "";
my @lines = split /\n/, $f;
foreach my $line (@lines) {
  if ($line =~ m/^open1$/ .. $line =~ m/^close1$/) {
    $matches .= "$line\n";
  }
}
```

Note, it is possible to use arbitrary Perl expressions as operands of the range operator. I wouldn't recommend this code, as it is not very efficient, and not very readable. At the same time it is easy to adapt the first example to the case where the `open1` and `close1` markers are included into the set of matches, e.g.:

```
my @matches = ( $f =~ m/\bopen1\b(.*?)\bclose1\b/gs );
for my $m (@matches) {
  print "open1${m}close1\n";
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you explained why the flipflop doesn't work.

Comment: @simbabque, I have added the explanations. I think you can remove your down vote now.

Comment: That wasn't mine. Your answer was already good, but could be improved.

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite how `$f` is generated so that it takes advantage of the flip-flop inside a `while` loop:

```
my ( $f, $matched );
while ( <> ) {
    $f .= $_;
    $matched .= $_ if /open1/ .. /close1/;
}
```

Comment: `$matched` is empty when I test with `$f = "xxx open1 ddd close1 mmm";`

Comment: @JasmineLognnes are "open1" and "close1" on separate lines?

Comment: @Jasmine Lognnes, If you had actually passed `xxx open1 ddd close1 mmm` to STDIN, it would have worked. You must have changed something.

Comment: You don't know if the start and end markers are on separate lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can also employ [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html). To get what is between the first pair of `open1` and `close1`

```
my $open_to_close = (split /open1|close1/, $f)[1];
```

The delimiter can be either `open1` or `close1`, so returned is a list of three elements: before `open1`, between them, and after `close1`. We take the second element.

---

If there are more `open1`/`close1` pairs take all odd-indexed elements.

Either get the array as well

```
my @parts = split /open1|close1/, $f;

my @all_open_to_close = @parts[ grep { $_ & 1 } 0..$#parts ];
```

or get it directly from the list

```
my @all_open_to_close = 
    grep { CORE::state $i; ++$i % 2 == 0 }  split /open1|close1/, $f;
```

The [state](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/state.html) is a [feature](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html)
from `v5.10`. If you already `use` that you don't need `CORE::` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to create a new inputs stream out of the contents of `$f`.

```
open my $fh, '<', \$f;
while (<$fh>) {
    if (/open1/ .. /close1/) {
        ...
    }
}
```